# Proper way to make a timer work with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python

I'm writing a script to execute an external program (ordinary pop-up window) for certain time (5 sec), get text from its title and terminate.

But the timer starts working only after I close popup window manually. Also I get programming environment (PyCharm in ms windows 7 + python 2.7) title instead of the title of called window.

```
import time, subprocess, win32gui

def worker(programpath):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(programpath)
    starttime = time.time()
    while time.time() - starttime < 5:
        proc.wait()
        proc_text=win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
        res, res2 = proc.communicate()
    proc.terminate()
    print res, res2, proc_text

worker()
```

Can you please show the right way to dealing with it?

Comment: The `.communicate()` call is blocking.  It basically means "wait for the subprocess to print something, then return that something."

Comment: Well, even if I make line with .communicate() as comment #, execution is still freeze right on first iteration in "while"-block and doesn't continue until I close called in Popen() program.
Or I just misunderstand something.

Comment: I imagine `proc.wait()` is blocking as well...

Comment: Oh, exactly. That worked. Many thanks!

Still have no idea how get text from poped-up window.